# Docker - PostgreSQL could not connect to server: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony, docker-compose

Trying to dockerise my Symfony 4 app, running with PostgreSQL

But when I'm running :

```
$ sudo docker-compose build
```

I'm having this error :

> In **AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 73:**
>
> An exception occurred in driver: **SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server : Connection refused :**
> Is the server running on host **"127.0.0.1"** and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port **5432**?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version:  '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: ${POSTGRES_IMAGE}
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    user: 1000:1000
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - .:/var/www/symfony
    working_dir: /var/www/symfony
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Content of my `.env` file

```
DATABASE_NAME=db
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root

## Docker images (name and version)
PHP_IMAGE=php:7.3-fpm
POSTGRES_IMAGE=postgres
```

Also **FYI** :

```
$ sudo docker-compose config
```

```
debian@debian:~/dev/symfony$ sudo docker-compose config
services:
  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mrd
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
  php:
    build:
      context: /home/debian/dev/symfony
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: on-failure
    user: 1000:1000
    volumes:
    - /home/debian/dev/symfony:/var/www/symfony:rw
    working_dir: /var/www/symfony
version: '3.7'
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

RUN apt-get update

# Install Postgres PDO
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
 && apt-get install -y zip \
 && docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo_pgsql \
 && apt-get install -y git

RUN pecl install apcu

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" \
    && php composer-setup.php --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN ls -larth
COPY . /var/www/symfony

RUN PATH=$PATH:/var/www/symfony/vendor/bin:bin

RUN pwd \
    && ls \
    && composer install --no-interaction --no-ansi --optimize-autoloader\
    && php bin/console doctrine:database:create \
    && php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --no-interaction \
    && php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
```

Has anybody a clue on why it does this ? And how to solve it ?

Searched a lot, and couldn't find anything that worked. Thought the `depends_on: db` would do the trick, but no.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232137/github-action-docker-database-migration-fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run:

```
docker-compose ps
```

[see Container name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaH7u.png)

Set DATABASE_HOST=Container name

```
DATABASE_NAME=db
DATABASE_HOST=## paste Container name
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root

## Docker images (name and version)
PHP_IMAGE=php:7.3-fpm
POSTGRES_IMAGE=postgres
```

Comment: Indeed, DATABASE_HOST should be the container name (not IP or hostname) which can be found with `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 0):

The pastes in your question indicate a number of things to be addressed with your `docker-compose.yml` file:

1. You are missing an `env_file:` entry for your `.env` file
2. You are missing an `image` for the `php` service
3. You specify `.` as your build context (which should be a directory that indicates where your `Dockerfile` is located)
4. You specify a path as your Dockerfile (which should be a filename, not a directory) -- I guess this might all work, but it's a bit confusing to read
5. Indentation for `-db` and `- /home/debian/dev/symfony:/var/www/symfony:rw` is off -- this might not be a problem, but it's still difficult to read

From your question about `build` failing with an error regarding inability to connect to a database -- could you update your question and share your `Dockerfile` for symfony?  I suspect that you need to remove a reference to a database connection.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message. (1) As my `docker-compose.yml` is in root with my `.env` file, I don't think it changes anything, it detects it automatically no ? (2) My Image is in my `Dockerfile` that I didn't shared and but I added to my question message (3) Seems working anyway, but ok, I'll watch for this (4) It's a file no ? Don't understand why you say here it's a directory ? (5) Ok I added the `Dockerfile` Thanks!